# Getting an "unterminated subpattern" error I don't understand

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-re

I'm learning Python from No Starches book on Python Automate the Boring Stuff. For a project we write a script to scrape the phone numbers from the text on the clipboard.

I'm getting an error (shown below). What did I do wrong and how can I fix it?

My code:

```
import re

# Phone number regex
phoneRegex = re.compile(r'''(
(\d{3}|\(\d{3}\))?             #area code
(\s|-|\.)?                     #seperator
(\d{3}\)                       #first 3 digits
(\s|-|\.)                      #seperator
(\d{4})                        #last 4 digits
(\s*(ext|x|ext.)\s*(\d{2,5}))? #extension
)''', re.VERBOSE)
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "*path snipped for privacy*/Automate the Boring Stuff with Python/Chapter 7 project phoneAndEmail.py", line 7, in <module>
    phoneRegex = re.compile(r'''(
  File "/Applications/Mu Editor.app/Contents/Resources/Python/lib/python3.8/re.py", line 252, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/Applications/Mu Editor.app/Contents/Resources/Python/lib/python3.8/re.py", line 304, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/Applications/Mu Editor.app/Contents/Resources/Python/lib/python3.8/sre_compile.py", line 764, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
  File "/Applications/Mu Editor.app/Contents/Resources/Python/lib/python3.8/sre_parse.py", line 948, in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, state, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)
  File "/Applications/Mu Editor.app/Contents/Resources/Python/lib/python3.8/sre_parse.py", line 443, in _parse_sub
    itemsappend(_parse(source, state, verbose, nested + 1,
  File "/Applications/Mu Editor.app/Contents/Resources/Python/lib/python3.8/sre_parse.py", line 836, in _parse
    raise source.error("missing ), unterminated subpattern",
re.error: missing ), unterminated subpattern at position 0 (line 1, column 1)
```

Comment: can you provide an example text for matching?

Comment: Hello, the book tasks the learner with going to "https://nostarch.com/contactus" then selecting all and copying the text to the clipboard. Then the script runs using that text for matching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake is in this part of the `phoneRegex` pattern:

```
(\d{3}\)
```

The opening `(` is the beginning of a group, but the closing `)` was escaped with a `\`, making it a literal `)` instead of the end of the group.

Thus, the opening `(` of the group is never balanced by a closing `)` (i.e., the group, a subpattern, is "unterminated").

You should change `\)` to `)`.

Comment: Your answer doesn't explain what the problem was and how you solved it. I didn't even find what you changed before writing my answer.

Comment: @darth see [answer].

Answer (score -1):

```
#! python3
# phoneAndEmail.py - Finds phone numbers and email addresses on the clipboard.

import pyperclip, re

phoneRegex = re.compile(r'''(
    (\d{3}|\(\d{3}\))? # area code
    (\s|-|\.)?         # separator
    (\d{3})              # first 3 digits
    (\s|-|\.)          # separator
    (\d{4})              # last 4 digits
    (\s*(ext|x|ext.)\s*(\d{2,5}))?  # extension
    )''', re.VERBOSE)

# Create email regex.
emailRegex = re.compile(r'''(
    [a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+      # username
    @                      # @ symbol
    [a-zA-Z0-9.-]+         # domain name
    (\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}){1,2} # dot-something
    )''', re.VERBOSE)

# Find matches in clipboard text.
text = str(pyperclip.paste())

matches = []
for groups in phoneRegex.findall(text):
    phoneNum = '-'.join([groups[1], groups[3], groups[5]])
    if groups[8] != '':
        phoneNum += ' x' + groups[8]
    matches.append(phoneNum)
for groups in emailRegex.findall(text):
    matches.append(groups[0])
```

Comment: Hello darth baba. Thank you as well! I see your change now and it is indeed correct. Really appreciate your help.